# How to set a counter everytime I click a submit button with Bootstrap slider in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I'm making a survey, everytime the user press "Continuar" it goes to the next question with a slider (it's everything on the same page), I want to store how many times the user has clicked "Continuar" to make a couple of validations.

I tried to use a php session but after a couple of test echoes it doesn't seem like any of the ifs are working as it doesn't show me anything when I load my page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $f1="nulo";

    if (empty($_SESSION['cont'])){
        $_SESSION['cont']=0;
    }

    // if button is pressed, increment counter
    if(isset($_POST['submitbttn'])) {
        ++$_SESSION['cont'];
        echo $_SESSION['cont'];
    }
    if ($_SESSION['cont'] == 1){
        echo "uno";
    }    
?>
```

```
<!-- Button --> 
 <form method="post">
     <button><a href="#carouselExampleControls" class="btn btn-default" role="button" style="background: #62b539; width:140px; height: 52px;" data-slide="next" input type="submit" name="submitbttn">Continuar</a></button>
     <br></br>
 </form>
```

I expect it to show the counter so I make sure it's working and I can make the validations I have to make

Comment: Your echo isn't correct: `echo $_SESSION['cont'];`

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submitbttn']))` you don't have an element with that name in the form.

Comment: Also, your markup for that button is... weird. Like the stray `a` and `input`. And `type="submit"` for a `button`. And the fact that you close an `a` that you never opened.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca assigned name="submitbttn" to the button, still doesn't work though :(

Comment: @imvain2 changed that part, still doesn't work

Comment: Please, update your question with correct code (the html, I mean)

Comment: Wrong button code: <button class="btn btn-default" role="button" style="background: #62b539; width:140px; height: 52px;" data-slide="next"  type="submit" name="submitbttn">Continuar</button>

Comment: `name="submitbbtn"` != `$_POST['submitbttn']` watch out for that name

Comment: @imvain2 without the href the slider doesn't work though :(

Comment: @EternalGrey then remove the `button` tag and use something else to check whether the form was submitted correctly, like an hidden `input` field

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca what would be the correct way?

Comment: Why did you add `a href` in `button` tag?

Comment: @EternalGrey the correct way would be to use the same name in the `name` attribute of the button and in the `$_POST` array. One is "submitbbtn" and the other is "submitbttn" at the moment.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar need the href for the slide to work

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca alright, fixed that part, guess it doesn't work because i made the button in the wrong way but idk how to make it work as i want, if i get rid of the href i will ruin the slider :(

Comment: Rewrite the slider so it works with a button/input.

Comment: @user3783243 is it the only way? i took the slider from the bootstrap webpage and I'm not sure if i can do that (or how)

Comment: Can you add a link to it, it probably is listening for some event. If you modify the event it should work.